# why does a Body Tag shift if you have a child with a top margin

Tags: html, css, position, google-chrome-devtools

I have spent a good chunk of my time to figure this out. In case you have a div with some margin on the top. The `body` position as per the chrome dev tools start from the point where the div starts from. Basically it doesn't consider the margin for the offset. Though it does considers the same for height calculation.

Eg -

```
<body>
    <div> my content my content my content my content my content my content my content my
    </div>
</body>
```

I have created a jsFiddle for the same -- http://jsfiddle.net/tusharmathur/kW4v4/

Comment: What? http://jsfiddle.net/kW4v4/1/

Comment: Body size in chrome dev tools seems to be - 11160px which is equal to the div containing the text. Now if the body is starting from the top of the iframe then how could they both have the same height? I hope you get my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of collapsing margins: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

This means that, when there is no padding or border getting in the way, two elements in the document flow will share their margins, like one big happy family.

`body` is absorbing the top margin of `div`.

This has been part of spec for aeons.

You can add 1px of padding or border to `body` to stop it from happening.

More details on collapsing margins can be found here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing