# CSS child elements "margin-top" property affects parent element

Tags: css, html

In HTML 5 with doctype  , I have inside body:

```
<div style="width:100%; background-color: #cccccc;">
    <div style="margin-top:20px; width:100px; background-color: #aa0000;">Sub</div>
    Main
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F3kXw/

When I render in firefox, I getting outer div have margin 20px from top of page,
what I need only sub div have margin 20px from the outer div. It works if I put character on top of sub div like:

```
<div style="width:100%; background-color: #cccccc;">
    Main
    <div style="margin-top:20px; width:100px; background-color: #aa0000;">Sub</div>
    Main
</div>
```

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/F3kXw/2/

It makes no sense to me, I never have had this problem in the past.

Comment: Searching for that exact title gave me the wanted answer in google, it was a previous [question here in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20689575/938236). That lead me to the original.

Comment: I just answered this yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21450924/2388219

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset? If not, I recommend http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/. This makes a huge difference in avoiding pixel differences among browsers.

Comment: Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/F3kXw/5/?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code maybe can help

```
<div class="website_sub_frame" style="width:100%; background-color: #cccccc;overflow:hidden">

    <div style="clear:both; margin-top:20px; width:100px; background-color: #aa0000;">Sub</div>
    Main
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using margin top why don't you add another div above your sub div and give it a height of say 20px.
eg:
    div class="website_sub_frame" style="width:100%; background-color: #cccccc;"
        div style="height:30px">Sub /div
        Main
    /div

Answer (score 0):

Try to give `margin-bottom` instead `margin-top` to child div. That's it.

```
<div class="website_sub_frame" style="width:100%; background-color: #cccccc;">
    <div style="width:100px; background-color: #aa0000; margin-bottom:20px;">Sub</div>
    Main
</div>
```

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F3kXw/3/)

OR you are looking for this?

```
<div class="website_sub_frame" style="width:100%; background-color: #cccccc;">
    Main
    <div style="width:100px; background-color: #aa0000; margin-top:20px;">Sub</div>
</div>
```

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F3kXw/4/)

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Make the parent DIV float. Not exactly sure why that fixes it, but it works.

```
 <div style="float:left; width:100%; background-color: #cccccc;">
   <div style="margin-top:20px; width:100px; background-color: #aa0000;">Sub</div>
   Main
</div>
```